# Why the density is sometimes interchanged with mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, fluid-dynamics

I don't know if this is a silly or an stupid question, but why, on some equations, the density is swapped with mass?

For Example, in the Naiver-Stokes equation (which from what I understand) is a way of writing Newton's second law of motion for fluids, uses the density insted of mass:

$$
\rho\frac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm dt} = -\nabla p + \nabla \cdot \tau + \rho g
$$

As seen above:
$$
\rho\frac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm dt}
$$
is a way of writting:
$$
F = m\frac{\mathrm d v}{\mathrm dt}
$$
But not even the units of the magnitudes match. The Newton units are $kg \cdot m \cdot s^{-2}$. If instead, you use density as "mass", now the units are $kg \cdot m^{-2} \cdot s^{-2}$. I understand that is almost impossible to know the whole mass of the atmosphere, or the whole mass of a river, so it will be more useful to use a magnitud that does not change and is easy to measure while analizing a fluid.

There are also other examples as the Bernouilli Equations:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 + \rho g h
$$
an equation that is pretty similar to the Mechanical Energy equation, but again, swapping mass with density.
$$
\frac{1}{2} m v^2 + m g h
$$

The thing is, why this equations works in the describing real fenomena (at macroscopic level) if they are not 100% equal to Newton's laws.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe it stems from dealing with a continuum object, this object can distort and stretch so it's easier to deal with a volume instead of a set amount of material. They even switch the $F$ in newton's laws for the force density $f$ = $F/V$. Then you can just imagine they are doing $\frac{F=m a}{V}\to f =\rho a$. Usually most derivations cover why they do this.

Comment: We've divided both sides of the equation by volume. Density is just mass per unit volume so multiply both sides by a unit volume to convert it to an equation in the mass.

Comment: These equations stand for infinitesimally small volumes of the fluids, and most of the quantities (e.g. $\rho$ and $p$) depends on the location ($\rho(\underline{r}$), $p(\underline{r})$).

Comment: The NS equations are expressed differentially per unit spatial volume, and has units of Force per unit volume.